# When loading a page set a radio button value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm having a problem with the first load off the page i want to check the "24h" radiobutton and when I do that when I use the custom date and do the apply it doesn't work.

It always load the 24h chart instead of the custom date like this one `StartDate: 20:00 17-05-2011`
 `EndDate: 22:00 17-05-2011`

My application page is this one http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=17236:555

username: user
password: 123qweASD

Can anyone help me with this, you can go to the application a try.

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles, please.

Comment: Ok, tanks for teaching me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your page would work better (and more naturally) if "Custom" was a 5th button in the radio group rather than a separate checkbox.  As it is your radio group has no valid value when the Custom checkbox is checked, and indeed it stays set to "24" although disabled.

Otherwise, you need to code the chart in such as way that it ignores the radiogroup setting when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: but that it working, you can try it, the problem is when i put in the page load the radio button with "24h". I just wanted one time load the 24h so when application run i show a chart in the beginning

Comment: On page submit you could set the radio group value to null when the checkbox has been checked - you could use a computation or a process to do that.

Comment: Is this way we verify the check `IF (:P999_CHECK = 'Y') THEN` ?

Comment: Yes, or that could be used in the condition property of the computation/process

Comment: Ok, so i have to do something like this `IF ( :P4_CHECK = null AND :P4_RADIOGROUP = null) THEN  
    :P4_RADIOGROUP := '24h'; 
  END IF;` but i think is not accepting the `:P4_CHECK = null`. Is there another way to see if `P4_CHECK` is not checked?

Comment: You have to write "is null" not "= null"

Comment: is this 2 cases in '24h' and the check button it works but when when i'm going to the others radiobutton it redirects to the '24h'. I have to fin d another way to do this.

Comment: i was trying to run onload a condition in JavaScript like this code `$v('P4_CHECK')=='Y' && $v('P4_RADIOGROUP') == null` and then set the value to 24h. Should this work?